# QT Creator / Designer : Files CANNOT be edited in Designer mode anymore

Tags: forms, qt, qt-creator, qt-designer

So when using Qt to build user interfaces, you all know that .ui files (forms) open in Designer mode by default, and that if you manually switch back to the Editor, then this message appears "This file can only be edited in Designer-mode".

Well, for some reason, and at some point, my file now opens BY DEFAULT in the editor, and the message does not show up. Worse, when manually switching to Designer mode, the main editing field is gray and empty and none of my stuff shows up ... Also no scroll bars or anything.

EDIT : actually, it is whichever form was loaded last that appears. And it is editable and all ... only the drop-down menu with the file name clearly indicates that it is MY file that is opened. When I perform an edit, then the edit is performed to this same last-opened form, and is reflected upon compiling. My display remains unchanged to the state that it had the last time that I was able to open it in the Designer.

EDIT : Also, along with the fact that my .ui file now opens by default in the Editor, it is also editable there like any other source file. But edits don't seem to bother, I modified some stuff or added gibberish, and it never showed after compiling nor did the compiler ever complaine ...

What's going on ? What did I do ? I have no crash nor any recent weird events to report ... It just suddenly started happening.

Thanks in advance for any clues,
Charles

Comment: Can you show a screenshot?

Comment: A screenshot of what ?

Comment: A screenshot of the error message.

Comment: Which error message ? There is none that I can see.